# Как вставить комментарий в XML документ?

Tags: java, xml

Ниже код моей функции. Возможно, моя проблема заключается в том, что я неправильно понял как работает insertBefore. Работу этого метода я понял так, insertBefore имеет два параметра: первый параметр - узел, который хотим вставить, второй параметр - перед каким узлом хотим вставить. Вызываем сам метод insertBefore у того узла, для которого нововставленный узел будет дочерним. Если все так, тогда не могу понять, почему данный код не вставляет комментарий там, где нужно.

```
public static Document addCommentsToDocument(Object obj, String tagName, String comment) throws Exception{
        String fileName = new String("/home/albuquerque/XML.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(file);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Node root = document.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList listNode = root.getChildNodes();
        Comment com = document.createComment(comment);
        for (int i = 0; i < listNode.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = listNode.item(i);
            root.insertBefore(com, node);
        }
return document;
}
```

Ниже код XML. Перед каждым тегом, кроме родительского нужно вставить комментарий.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<example>
    <a>a</a>
    <b>b</b>
    <string1>string1</string1>
    <string2>string2</string2>
</example>
```

Но вставка происходит такая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><example>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <string1>string1</string1>
    <string2>string2</string2><!--it's a comment-->
</example>
```

Что не так я делаю?

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы одну и ту же ноду-коммент вставляете. В итоге она оказывается в конце. Нужно в цикле создавать новые узлы-комментарии и их вставлять.

Comment: @Alexander, вчера еще исправил это, но не понял как. Все верно, вот как я исправил это
  `n.getParentNode().insertBefore(document.createComment(comment), n);`


Я просто узел вставлял перед каждым елементом xml и следующей итерацией передвигал в итоге он в конце оказался у последнего, так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент вставлялся неправильно из-за того, что узел-комментарий был один и просто передвигался от одного элемента к другому, передвигаясь к самому последнему внутреннему элементу родительского тега. Решением оказалось создание на каждой итерации нового узла-коммента и добавлением его к нужному элементу.

```
n.getParentNode().insertBefore(document.createComment(comment), n);
```

- n.getParentNode() - родитель для узла-комментария. Вызывать метод insertBefore() нужно как раз у подразумеваемого родителя.
- далее нужно в insertBefore передать два аргумента. Первый аргумент - то, что нужно вставить. Второй аргумент - перед чем нужно вставить.